# How to choose the subscription where the new resource is created on Windows Azure portal?

Tags: azure

I might be missing something obvious with the new Management Portal for Windows Azure, but how do I select the subscription where the new resource (compute, storage, site, ...) is being created? Can someone pinpoint where the subscription selection takes place in the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a VM the first step(midway down the pane) has a section for choosing which subscription to deploy against.  See picture for location:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You specify the subscription on the last panel.

New -> Data Service -> Storage -> Quick Create -> Url/Region/Subscription